# Do you get anything for getting 100 percent sync in Assassins Creed 3 The Tyranny of King Washington?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Is there a reward for getting 100% sync in Assassins Creed 3: The Tyranny of King Washington?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is one silver trophy that specifically requires a 100% synchronization:

> Frontiersman
>
> Reach 100% synchronization in the Frontier.

https://www.truetrophies.com/t1551/frontiersman-trophy

Comment: So u don't get any outfits or weapons for the main game

Comment: @MorganMillar Not that I'm aware of. If this answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted, and then please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand what questions are acceptable on this site. Welcome to Stack Exchange!